# How to specify admob library in build.gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, admob, android-studio

Can I specify the AdMob library in the build.gradle in Android Studio to avoid having the AdMob jar locally?

I've tried

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.ads:6.2.1+'
}
```

but it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The latest version of Google Mobile Ads SDK for Android was released as part of Google Play services 4.0 (See [Release Notes on Blog](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com.es/2013/10/upgrade-to-new-google-mobile-ads-sdk.html))

**NOTE the following limitation:**

> The Google Mobile Ads APIs in Google Play services currently does not
>   support DoubleClick For Publishers (DFP), Ad Exchange, or Search Ads
>   for Mobile Apps.

So all you need in your gradle dependencies for Google AdMob:

```
dependencies {
    // ... Other entries
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
}
```

The rest of the setup is explained here:

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/

With my project it didn't work to load ads directly after adding the support as described on the docs. Instead it crashed initializing the layout.

What helped was one of the following things:

- "Sync Project with Gradle File" button on the menu bar
- Check "Project Structure" for errors about wrong linked libs (shown as a red bar on the bottom of the dialog if any)
- "Invalidate Caches / Restart"
- Rebuild Project (To include trigger of "Clean")
- Maybe waiting a little to get ads? (Retested it hours later again and finally it worked like charm)

Answer (score 13):

Better if you use following:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
```

Because, it will reduce your apk file size.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think the google admob files are available on maven central. I think the only thing you can do is reference them locally

Answer (score 0):

You need to include in you root build.gradle

```
 allprojects {
      repositories {
          maven {
              url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
          }
       }
     }
```

Then in your app/build.gradle you include

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
```

in your dependencies block. You must also this line at the bottom of your app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of Android Studio, it's this:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
```